# jQuery Regex not picking up

Tags: jquery, html, regex

ok, so I have checked about 4 different SO Questions and none have given me the answer. :(

A website I am working on had a few hundred pages but unfortunately the structure of the tags in the url has changed. and guess what, the pages are hard coded with text and links (FML) anyway a quick fix for now would be to get query to change all these links.

I decided to try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').each(function() {

    var str2 = "tag=";
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if(link.indexOf(str2) != -1){

        var link = link.replace("/tag=.*/","tag/$1");
        $(this).attr('href', link);
    }
});

})
```

What I need is to get the value of the 'href' scan for the 'tag=ecommerce' or 'tag=b2b' etc and change the structure to 'tag/eccommerce' or 'tag/b2b'

However it just is not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: i don't know regex well, but placeholders can only be filled with brackets i think. so please try "/tag=(.*)/"

Comment: nope, tried that :/

Comment: got it: replace("tag=","tag/"). It's not a regex to select something out of a string. it's to replace something. so you don't need a real regex instead you need only a string that you want to replace in your link with another string.

Comment: sorry, i need the value after that as I am adding something else to the end. like /edit etc..

Comment: string concatenation. replace or cut what ever you need and add the rest with a plus. example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAgPZW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the regex syntax `/YourRegex/` instead of `"/YourRegex/"`. And use a capturing group like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').each(function() {

    var str2 = "tag=";
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if(link.indexOf(str2) != -1){

        var link = link.replace(/tag=(.*)/,"tag/$1");
        $(this).attr('href', link);
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.foo.com/tag=MyTag">MyLink</a>
```